# Image resize with php image magician

Tags: php, image

I'm using PHP IMAGE MAGICIAN for resizing the images of my website.

When I try to resize the image with a changed extension (e.g. changing `image.jpg` to `image.gif`), the function returns an error because the image is invalid in this situation. I want to avoid this error.

I tried a lot of methods to check is the image valid but without success.

The error which appear is:

> "file
>   /Users/.../uploads/1541963916_4dd672e5f3a3060ced41f3f7975453c9.gif is
>   missing or invalid"

Every image I upload to my website I am renaming to a new filename with its extension.

This is the part of code which I am using.

```
$workWithImage = new imageLib(UPLOADS_DIR . $original);
$workWithImage->resizeImage($width, $height, $type);
$workWithImage->saveImage(UPLOADS_DIR . $thumbnail, $imageQuality);
```

I searched for this problem but I could not find a solution.

Comment: please edit your question and add the error code as text...

Comment: check if you have write permissions to the directory you are trying to save the resized image

Comment: 1. I edited the error. "file /Users/.../uploads/1541963916_4dd672e5f3a3060ced41f3f7975453c9.gif is missing or invalid"

I have all permissions. The problem is when the image is invalid as I said. With valid images it works normal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looking at source this library seems to not handle this situation at all. You can create bug report at library home page. What you can do is compare mime type of file with it's extension and either do you own error handling or rename file name to have correct extension. Mime type detection code used by this library is

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
finfo_close($finfo);
switch($mimeType) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/gif':
    case 'image/png':
    case 'image/bmp':
    case 'image/x-windows-bmp':
        $isImage = true;
        break;
    default:
        $isImage = false;
}
```